# get all selectors inside a div

Tags: jquery, selector, each

I'm trying to get all the selectors and get the height on that selector:

```
    var myDiv = $('#main-div').find('*').each(function(e){
        return this.id;
    });

    console.log(myDiv);
```

What I need is get the `height` and `width` of every element inside `#main-div`, and show into console like:

[selector, width , height]... each

Any ideas?

Comment: You can get IDs or classes on elements, but you cannot really retrieve the "selector" of an element. You can use `width()` and `height()` to get the dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/) to access all the elements inside the div and use [.height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/) and [.width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/) on them. Something like below should work (untested),

```
$.each ($('#main-div').children(), function (index) {
   console.log ('[' + this.tagName + ',' + $(this).height() + ',' + $(this).width() + ']');
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/e4aad/) here to show that it only access the immediate childrens and not goes inside the child element(s).

Comment: This will only access the immediate children.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery have **width** and **height** methods to do this

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var myDiv = $('#main-div').find('*').each(function(e){
    console.log( "id: " + $( this ).attr('id') + ", height:" + $( this ).height(  ) + ", width: " + $( this ).width(  ) 
});
```